# Webpack build fail if a specific dependency exists in bundle

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am a webpack newbie.

I am trying to modify our webpack.config.js so that the build should fail if some specific package is in the final build.

specific example is we don't want any dependency to use `fs` for our UI code.

Comment: I'm not sure about webpack, but you can try to configure `eslint` instead, so it throws an error when you use a restricted lib in your code.
Look at this rule - https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-imports

Comment: Thanks for this. But `eslint` would only check the imports in my source code right, it won't check imports in dependencies. I just don't want certain modules be present in the final build.